# Magento 2 Cannot add new role

Tags: magento

While adding new user role, the page is coming blank. Could anyone suggest any solution?

[image]

Comment: Try to Clear Cache folders in Var.

Comment: please provide your Magento version

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I have cleared the cache folders in Var, but no improvement.

Comment: Its Magento Version 2.1.1

Comment: Have you check consol or log file? Is that any thing there?